# How to implement Merge When Not Matched then Insert in SSIS dataflow task?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I got a situation loading from staging to Dimension tables. When loading to destination tables it is required to only insert New rows not the existing ones.
Below is the blueprint of my query. For some reasons i'm first inserting to temp table and then from temp to destination table.

```
    IF  OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp_Table') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE  #Temp_Table;
    CREATE TABLE #Temp_Table(col1 smallint identity(2,1),
                     col2 varchar(100),
                     col3 varchar(100)
                    )
    Insert into #Temp_Table( col2 ,
                             col3 
                            )
            SELECT DISTINCT Col2,
                            Col3
                     From Staging_Table
             left outer join Dimension_Table --to exclude already existing records


   INSERT INTO Dimension_Table(Col1,col2,col3)
           SELECT Col1, Col2, COl3
                 FROM #Temp_Table
```

SO far the query is working perfect. But, Col1 in Dimension_Table is primary Key. So when inserting, even though the row already exists in Dimension_Table, the row is getting inserted because I'm generating new col1(identity) value in temp_table. 
To be more clear, if the staging tables data is same like yesterdays...The rows being inserting by generating new PrimaryKey Values. I thought of Implementing below steps

1. Comparing staging and Dimension data
   MERGE ...When NotMatched....Then Insert to Temp_Table
2. Generate Identity column values(by creating a new column) to the existing data in temp table
3. Insert from Temp_Table to Dimension_Table

**Can someone help me how to implement this using ssis???**

Comment: Why you have added identity in Temp_Table? Why not using the identity in Dimension_Table?

Answer (score 1):

you could do an update select to populate your temp table with the ID's in your destination table. The query would probably look something like this:

```
UPDATE tempTable
SET tempTable.col1 = destination.col1
FROM #Temp_Table tempTable 
INNER JOIN Dimension_Table destination 
ON tempTable.col2 = destination.col2 AND tempTable.col3 = destination.col3
```

Of course to do this you would have to remove the identity specification on column1 in your temp table to insert. Next, all you would need to do is to select all the rows where col1 is null in your temptable.

For the SSIS implementation, there is a task called "LookUp". You can select columns to lookup and SSIS will give you two different outputs. One where the rows match the lookup and another where the rows do not match the lookup. From there, you can do what you need to do with each solution set.